# FeynCalc Phi4 example error with FeynRules

Tags: feyncalc

[image]I'm starting on FeynCalc and was trying to run through a few examples coming with the package. For the ones of which the models are generated by FeynRules, it doesn't work out well. (When the model is included in the FeynCalc package, it works fine.) I read somewhere that there might be some incompatibility between FeynRules and Mathematica 11 and not for previous versions. I'm using Mathematica 12.2; could that be the problem or is it due to something else? Attached is the code..ps. I already evaluated the GenerateModelPhi4.m as the documentation suggested. Thanks in advance!

```
MakeBoxes[p1,TraditionalForm]:="\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \      (1\)]\)";
MakeBoxes[p2,TraditionalForm]:="\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)";
MakeBoxes[k1,TraditionalForm]:="\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(1\)]\)";
MakeBoxes[k2,TraditionalForm]:="\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2\)]\)";

diags = InsertFields[CreateTopologies[1, 2 -> 2,
    ExcludeTopologies->{WFCorrections}],
    {S[1],S[1]}-> {S[1],S[1]}, InsertionLevel -> {Classes},
    Model -> FileNameJoin[{"Phi4","Phi4"}]];
Paint[diags, ColumnsXRows -> {3, 1}, Numbering ->       None,SheetHeader->None, ImageSize->{512,256}];
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using as text.

Comment: I have included the code as text. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: You might put that information into a self-answer, if you think another user might benefit from your experience down the line. Self-answers are welcome on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I've cleared the issue. The error comes from running the model generating file and the actual calculation on the same Kernel. To solve it, one just opens a separate Kernel to do the calculations.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, here I want to also illustrate those messages about `$CharacterEncoding`.

The `FeynRules` package is writing files with `OpenWrite`, but didn't set the `CharacterEncoding` for it. As the metadata in this model file includes european diacritical characters, they were encoded like `CharacterEncoding -> WindowsANSI`.

And the `FeynArts` package is reading model files with `Get`, which defaults to use `$CharacterEncoding`, it won't be able to read a `WindowsANSI` encoded file if you've set it to `UTF8` etc. .